# CRUD with external REST service as Model in Loopback

Tags: rest, model-view-controller, crud, loopbackjs, strongloop

A couple quick questions:

1. I would like to use an external REST API service (e.g. AgileCRM). With their service, I would like to use the REST Connector within a model that allows me to CRUD AgileCRM's API. Is this possible? If so, what model should be the base (e.g. PersistedModel, Model, etc)?
2. I would like to merge data from AgileCRM and a PersistedModel (e.g. MySQL). Should I do this via relationships OR inheritance? If inheritance, which should be the parent model? It would be ideal to use all data from AgileCRM (represented as a model in LB, if possible) and add information from a local MySQL database.
3. Have you any thoughts on wrapping an API service (e.g. AgileCRM) as a connector type (e.g. REST Connector for AgileCRM, based on REST Connector)? AgileCRM has many features but their CRUD methods operate slightly different from how LB interacts with data sources.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question, sorry it never got answered, but it's also very broad is some portions. I would recommend asking shorter, more specific questions, and making multiple StackOverflow questions for them.

That said, here's some brief answers for people reading this entry:

1. Yes, this is possible. Check out the [REST connector](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/REST+connector).
2. I would probably use multiple parent models that are internal and then a single exposed REST model (not "persisted") that collates that data together.
3. Sure, you could do that. Writing a connector isn't too difficult, check out our docs on [building a connector](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Building+a+connector).